# How to import python packages across projects

Tags: python

I want to have a generic project in python which has packages and modules that can be used in multiple other projects.
I want to know how can I import generic projects packages and modules in other projects. Say

A Generic Project which has re-usable/common code that can be used in multiple project

```
generic_project/
    package1/
        __init__.py
        module1/
    package2
        __init__.py
        module2/
```

and a Specific Project

```
project_1
    package3/
        __init__.py
        module3/
    package4/
        __init__.py
        module4/
```

How can I import module1(of generic project) in module3 (project1) ?
Just want to let you know that Generic project and Project 1 are two independent projects packaged and distributed separetly.

I have gone through similar questions but all of them mostly talk about referring packages with in a project.

Comment: you need to create an installable library out of `generic_project` and install it into your python environment

Comment: `$PYTHONPATH` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Both `generic_project` and `project_1` (and the `moduleX`s) have to include a `__init__.py` file to be considered (and treated) as packages.
2. `generic_project` needs to be installed (or simply present) as a package in either `package3` (near `module3`) or `[python installation path]\Lib`, so the python interpreter will consider looking for the following expression.
3. You access it like every python package - `from generic_project.package1 import module1` or `import generic_project.package1.module1`.